# How to get Hive Thrift Protocol version?

Tags: hive, version, thrift-protocol

I'm always getting the following Error on `Apache Hive Server2` when trying to connect to it using `Beeline` or `Apache Hue`:

> Sep 01, 2017 2:20:50 INFO: 17/09/01 14:20:50 ERROR TThreadPoolServer:
>   Thrift error occurred during processing of message.
>
> Sep 01, 2017 2:20:50 INFO: org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Missing version in
>   readMessageBegin, old client?
>
> Sep 01, 2017 2:20:50 INFO:   at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:228)
>       Sep 01, 2017 2:20:50 INFO:   at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:27) 
>       Sep 01, 2017 2:20:50 INFO:   at org.datapassport_project.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56) 
>       Sep 01, 2017 2:20:50 INFO:   at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286) 
>       Sep 01, 2017 2:20:50 INFO:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
>       Sep 01, 2017 2:20:50 INFO:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
>       Sep 01, 2017 2:20:50 INFO:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The error information indicates that my JDBC client is using the wrong Thrift protocol (TProtocol) version.

So I'm trying to find the right version to use, but I cannot find it configured in any Hive property.

How can I find the thrift protocol version being used here?